# Google Sheets script will not function (Cell reference out of range)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The following script I have with the purpose of automatically sorting things does not work, and returns with "Exception: Cell reference out of range onEdit Code.gs.6 (which directs you to range.sort, placing you after the .)

Does anyone know a fix to this?

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("STANDINGS");
var range = sheet.getRange("S5:Y8");

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 5, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "STANDINGS") {
    //e.source.toast("Flag1")
    sh.getRange("S5:Y8").sort([{ column: 23, ascending: true }]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This came back with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:7", which is referencing e.range.getSheet()

Comment: This is not the sort of function you can run from the script editor.  Paste it into the the script editor and save it and then go to sheet STANDINGS and edit something on that sheet